# Dual monitor on iGPU not working

Tags: multiple-monitors, intel-graphics, hdmi, intel, vga

If I boot using the HDMI output from the motherboard, the HDMI output will work and the others won't work. If I boot using the VGA output, the motherboard will only enable the VGA output and the other display outputs won't work.

My hardware is:

- Motherboard: MSI H510M PRO
- CPU: i5-11400

Answer (score 0):

I read that there was a guy that solved this issue by downloading MSI utilities. He managed to get two monitors on his MSI B560M mobo. There are probably some settings you need to tweak in MSI utilities.

Let me know if the above solves your problem.

Comment: Do you have a link to either the post about the guy who solved the issue? Which settings required tweaking? If you have this info, please [edit] your answer and add it.